# Install gems via ftp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, rubygems

Can you install your ruby gems via ftp? I mean just copy your local gem directory `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems` and put it online with filezilla in the `ruby>gems>gems` directory.

The reason I want to do this is because with cPanel it gives me errors when trying to install some gems (like permission errors, some require ruby >=1.9.2 but I already have ruby 1.9.3). So is there a simple way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying your system's gem which may be ruby version specific, you could place all the required gems sources in your application's lib directory and reference them in your Gemfile.  Not that you cannot place these sources in other directories.

Place gem source in your local application e.g. `#{Rails.root}/lib/my_gem` and update your `Gemfile` to reference the gem using:

```
gem "my_gem", path: "lib/my_gem"
```

Then run `bundle install` to install the sourced gem in your application.

Answer (score 0):

and you can run

gem server

then add the source

http://some.ip:8808

there you'll have shared the gem installed in that system